# Unable to update the rootScope in angular

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, angular-controller, angularjs-rootscope

I am trying to send a request to a php file from one controller in angular and getting the response. I stored the response in a rootScope variable which is initialized in the controller.run() method with 0.

Now I am trying to use the updated rootScope in another controller in order to display the response from the php page. But the rootScope is not getting updated and it is still showing 0.

Here is my code.

The following is the run method where the rootScope is initialized

```
adminController.run(function ($rootScope) {
    $rootScope.n = 0;
});
```

The following is the code for controller 1 where I am requesting a response from the php page and updating the rootScope variable.

```
adminController.controller('adminLoginController', function($scope,$rootScope,$http,$window) {

    $scope.loginCheck = function(event,user){
        var request = $http({
            method: "post",
            url: "../_/php/loginCheck.php",
            headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'     }
        });
        request.success(function (data) {
            $rootScope.n=data;
            $rootScope.$apply();
            $window.location.href = 'admin.html#admin_home';       
        });
    }
});
```

Here is the code for my second controller where I am utilizing the rootScope variable. Here the problem comes as the rootScope is not getting updated and displaying me only the 0 with which it is initialized.

```
adminController.controller('adminHomeController', function($scope,$rootScope,$http,$window) {
    $scope.uname=$rootScope.n;
    alert($scope.uname);
});
```

Can some one let me know where I am going wrong.

Comment: `$rootScope.$apply();` Is not needed, a digest cycles runs automatically with `http`. Any console errors? Try putting a console log in your `.run` to see if it's rerunning on nav?

Comment: I think your controller load first then **$rootScope** value update. can you show more hint

Comment: @DylanWatt I tried logs in both the run method and the success method of controller 1. It is not showing the log of the controller 1. And yes the run method is running again...

Comment: @BaradwajAryasomayajula : If the suggestions solved your problem, you can mark mark any answer as accepted which you think best suited your requirement

Answer (score 3):

Your problem sounds like a timing issue. To communicate between controllers with `$rootScope`, you can set up an event to listen for changes.

**Update root scope:**

```
$rootScope.$broadcast('n', data);
```

**Listen for changes:**

```
$rootScope.$on('n', function (event, data) {
    //do something with new value 'data'
});
```

Comment: a reason for the downvote? it would be helpful not only to myself but anyone who reads this anwser

Answer (score 1):

**HTML**

```
<body ng-app="adminController">

<div ng-controller="adminLoginController">
        <button ng-click="loginCheck()">loginCheck</button>
    </div>

    <div ng-controller="adminHomeController">
    <button ng-click="getval()">getVal</button>
        rootscope val {{uname}}
    </div>
</body>
```

**controllers**

```
var app = angular.module('adminController', []);

app.run(function ($rootScope) {
    alert("run");
    $rootScope.n = 0;
});

adminController.controller('adminLoginController', function($scope,$rootScope,$http,$window) {

    $scope.loginCheck = function(){
        alert("Inside loginCheck");
        $rootScope.n = 1;      
    }
});

adminController.controller('adminHomeController', function($scope,$rootScope,$http,$window) {

    $scope.getval = function() {
        $scope.uname = $rootScope.n;
    } 
});
```

If both of your controllers instantiates at the same time, then you need to use even based notification as suggested by @aw04 using $broadcaste,$on and $emit.

Answer (score 1):

Put a `$watch` on the variable

```
adminController.controller('adminHomeController', function($scope,$rootScope,$http,$window) {
    $scope.$watch(
        function watchFn(){ return $rootScope.n; },
        function listener(newValue, oldValue) {
            $scope.uname=newValue;
        }
    );
});
```

For more information, see [AngularJS $watch API Reference](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#$watch)

---

Keep in mind that it is not wise to clutter `$rootScope` with data. Persistent data is better kept in a service.

```
app.factory("LoginCheck", function($http) {
    var n = 0;
    var request;
    function getN() { return n; };
    function setN(newN) { n = newN; return n; } 
    function getRequest { return request; };
    function check(user) { 
        request = $http({
            method: "post",
            url: "../_/php/loginCheck.php",
            headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'     }
        });
        var derivedRequest = request.then(function (response) {
            setN(response.data);
            //return for chaining
            return response;
        });       
        request = derivedRequest;
        return request;
    };
    return {
        getN: getN,
        setN: setN,
        getRequest: getRequest,
        check: check
    };
});
```

Then in your LoginController:

```
adminController.controller('adminLoginController', function($scope,$window,LoginCheck) {

    $scope.loginCheck = function(event,user){
        var req = LoginCheck.check(user);
        req.then(function (response) {
            $window.location.href = 'admin.html#admin_home';       
        }).catch(function (errorResponse) {
            console.log(errorResponse.status);
        });
    };
});
```

In your HomeController:

```
adminController.controller('adminHomeController', function($scope,LoginCheck) {
    if ( LoginCheck.getN() ) {
        $scope.uname = LoginCheck.getN();
    } else {
        LoginCheck.getRequest().then( function() {
            $scope.uname = LoginCheck.getN();
        });
    }; 
});
```